# how to update with , seprator with preivous value in mysql

Tags: mysql

$r ='insert into `posts` set id="'.$id.'", postId="'.$idus.'" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `whoLikes`= whoLikes,$idus'

like := ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new = new+'$new'

but i need:= ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new = new,'$new'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [MySQL concat() function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp):

```
... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `whoLikes`=CONCAT(`whoLikes`, $idus)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr talesid